# Immediately stop a loop even if its still running

Tags: c++, windows

This is a 2 part question so bear with me,

I am making a program in C++ and i want it to only run while button is pressed setting a value to true, i am using GetAsyncKeyState for this. The code:

```
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 1)
    {
        Start = true;
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)
    {
        Start = false;
    }
```

So when its pressed start will be true, and when when the button is up it will be false. But this isnt working and sets start to true instantly? is there another more reliable way to do this, or am i jsut being dumb?

My second question is, I want it to end instantly when Start is false even if its still running? the only thing i can think of is use an if statement after every single line but this seems impractical and i dont know if it will work:

```
while (Start == true);
        {
                GetCursorPos(&CursorPos);
                SetCursorPos(CursorPos.x + 0, CursorPos.y + 0);
                Sleep(500);
        {
```

This is repeated alot more by the way, any and all help would be greatly appreciated thanks
(if you need more information i will be happy to provide it)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Provide some [mre] in your question.** Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), and read the documentation of your compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...).

Comment: **Notice that `GetAsyncKeyState` is not part of the C++ standard.** Check by reading the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). On my Linux desktop, `GetAsyncKeyState`  does not exist. If you code for Windows, be sure to [read its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/) and to tag your question appropriately

Comment: You could be interested by open source libraries such as [libSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) and you should study their source code for inspiration. If your boss, client or teacher allows it, you could consider using them. You might also study -at least for inspiration- the source code of related open source projects on https://github.com/ or https://gitlab.com/

Comment: `while (Start == true);` You probably don't want that semicolon there.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose:

```
My second question is, I want it to end 
instantly when Start is false even if its still running?
```

You can break it whenever start becomes false so basically you can change the boolean variable and if it is false, break.